# Is Amazon music cloud the salvation? Do I "own" the music afterwards?

Tags: amazon, music, online-storage, cloud

As far as I understand, at **Amazon music cloud** for 30 dollars a year you can upload all your mp3 music that you have.

Even if you never payed for some of the mp3s, after those uploads, they are **treated as leagally owned**.

What will happen, if you cancel that 30 dollars per year?

Do you still legally own the songs, you once uploaded to the drive?

Comment: Note that Apple iTunes and Google Music have similar offers.

Comment: Then it's also the question: Do I Own them there? And Which is the best?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking the following question:

> If I [illegally] downloaded 1TB of songs from Napster in the year 2000, then I pay a 1 time $30 fee to Amazon, does that mean I now legally own all of that content?

IANAL: No, you do not own the content, All these services do is make it so you have the capability stream that content (as if from your computer), through their service. (Possibly in violation of their TOS.) Once you stop paying that subscription, you can no longer stream that content from them. Your rights to play illegally-acquired content are no different than from before your subscription.